# Piping node.js to python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, subprocess

I'm trying to test a somewhat simple node.js to python pipe thats non-blocking.

So far I have the following code

In test.js:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    console.log("hello");
process.exit(0);
```

In test.py:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading  import Thread
from Queue      import Queue, Empty

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    while True: 
        lines = out.readline()
        out.flush()
        queue.put(lines)

process = Popen("node test.js", stdout=PIPE)
queue = Queue()
thread = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(process.stdout, queue))
thread.daemon = True # kill all on exit
thread.start()

while True:
    try:
        char = queue.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        continue # do stuff
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
```

I expect the program to simply output hello 100 times, piping. But I get no output (run as:)

```
> python test.py
```

Comment: If I edit `enqueue_output` to include `print lines` I see the "hello"s, so assume the data must not be getting queued correctly, but the program is getting the output.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify line

```
process = Popen("node test.js", stdout=PIPE)
```

to:

```
process = Popen(['/usr/local/bin/node', 'test.js'], stdout=PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `process.exit(0)`. That is causing the process to exit before the writes to stdout have a chance to finish, since the writes are async on *nix when stdout is a pipe and not a tty. A call to `process.exit()` is almost never needed since the process should end naturally and 0 is the default exit status code anyway.

The [documentation for `process.stdout`/`process.stderr`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o) has recently been updated recently to describe the situations in which those streams will be sync or async.

Comment: Python is getting input though, I think it might be due to my usage of `Queue`. I removed the exit and the problem persists